# comparing a 1d array of integers to rows in 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a piece of code that is running, but is currently a bottleneck, and I was wondering whether there is a smarter way to do it.

I have a 1D array of integers between 0-20, with a length of 20-1000 (it varies) and I'm trying to compare it to a set of 1D arrays that are stored in a 2D array.
I wish to find any row in the 2D array that completely matches the 1D array.

My current approach to do this is the following:

```
res = np.mean(one_d_array == two_d_array,axis=1) == 1
```

The problem with this approach is that it will compare all elements in all rows, even if these rows don't match on the first element, second, ect... Which is of course very inefficient.
I could remedy this by looping through the rows and comparing each row individually, then I would probably be able to stop the comparison as soon as one element is false. However then I would be stuck with a slow for loop, which would also not be ideal.

So I'm wondering is there some other clever way to get the best of both of these approaches?

Comment: loops are not recommended with numpy. I think what you are doing is already pretty fast. Do you have to repeat this action many times? if so, maybe there is a way to combine them if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy has a few useful built-in functions for checking matrix/vector equality, this is about twice as fast:

```
import numpy as np
import time
x = np.random.random((1, 1000))
y = np.random.random((10000, 1000))
y[53] = x

t = time.time()
x_in_y = np.equal(x, y).all(axis=1)  # equal(x, y) returns a row x col matrix of True for matches; all(axis=0) returns a vector len(rows) if the entire row in x == y is true
idx = np.where(x_in_y)  # returns the indicies where x_in_y is true (here 53)
print(time.time() - t)  # 0.019975900650024414

t = time.time()
res = np.mean(x == y, axis=1) == 1
print(time.time() - t)  # 0.03999614715576172
```

Comment: I was trying out .all before but I ended up abandoning it because it summed over all axis, I didn't know you could use it with axis keyword.
Thanks!